# how to get wishlist id from Url Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, wishlist

Hi I am using magento enterprise. I am working in `wishlist` page and my url is:

http://myweburl/en/wishlist/index/share/wishlist_id/6/

How can I get wishlist id from URL?

Right now, I am trying to get id like this:

```
$wishlistId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('wishlist_id');
```

But its giving me:

> NULL

Why its giving me null instead of giving me 6?

Comment: Where are you trying to get this information? template, block, controller or helper?